# Is there a way to make a Java method that maps an SQL result list to an entity class generic?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this method that executes a native SQL query successfully. No issues. It maps the result list from the query to the relevant entity class:

```
@Data
public class DemoManager {

  Transaction transaction;
  static Session session;
  Query query;
  DemoEntity demoResultList;


  String url = "...";
  String username = "...";
  String password = "...";
  Class<DemoEntity> demoEntity = DemoEntity.class;


  public void executiveQuery(String sql) {
    session = Base.getSessionFactory(url, username, password, demoEntity).openSession();
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    query = session.createNativeQuery(sql, demoEntity);
    demoResultList = (DemoEntity) query.getResultList().get(0);
    session.close();
  }
```

Now, the problem. I want to make the `executeQuery()` method generic, so that when it is called, any entity class can be passed as an argument, instead of creating a new method whenever there is a new entity. To try achieve that, I tried this:

```
...

public static Class<T>  resultList;
Class<T> entity;

...

public <T> void executiveQuery(String sql, Class<T> entity) {
    session = Base.getSessionFactory(url, username, password, entity).openSession();
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    query = session.createNativeQuery(sql, entity);
    resultList = (entity) query.getResultList().get(0); // the entity on this line could not be compiled
    session.close();
  }
```

I couldn't get that method to compile. How do I make the `executiveQuery()` generic to accept any entity class so that I can get my database column returned in `returnList` like this:

```
public String getTestColmn() {
return resultList.getTestId();
```

}

And then call `executeQuery()` and pass any entity class to it, perhaps something like this:

```
public void callExecuteQuery(String sql, Class<T> entity) {
    demoManager.executeQuery(sql, DemoEntity.class);
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a method generic you need the class to be generic as well

```java
public class DemoManager<T> {

 T resultList;

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public void executiveQuery(String sql) {
    ...
    resultList = (T) query.getResultList().get(0);
    ...
 }
}

...

// And you need to change the creation of the `DemoManager`
DemoManager<DemoEntity> demoManager = new DemoManager<>(...);
demoManager.executiveQuery(sql);
String testColumn = demoManager.getResultList().getTestColmn();
```

Noting that if there is a type mismatch during the casting it will throw an error at runtime.

---

Another option is to have the `executeQuery` as static and get the `session` and the generic class as parameters

```java
public class DemoManager {

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public <T> static T executiveQuery(Session session, String sql, Class<T> entity) {
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    query = session.createNativeQuery(sql, demoEntity);
    return (entity) query.getResultList().get(0);
 }
}

...

Session session = ...;
DemoEntity entity = DemoManager.executiveQuery(session, sql, DemoEntity.class);
String testColumn = entity.getTestColumn();
```

Comment: It is worth pointing out that this is an _unchecked cast_: `resultList` could store an object of entirely the wrong type, and you'd only find out when you accessed it. You can do a checked cast by passing in a `Class<T>` somewhere (either to the constructor, or as a method parameter), and then use the methods on it to ensure that `resultList` is an instance of the correct type.

Comment: @AndyTurner, can you demonstrate what you mean in an answer box, please? Thanks

Comment: @Islam Elbanna, compilation error is thrown on the line `resultList = (T) query.getResultList().get(0);`

`Required Type: T,
Provided: T`

Comment: @Testilla I have updated the answer there shouldn't be `<T>` before `void` anymore

For the compilation error, check if there is any import by mistake of something with the same name as `T`

Comment: @IslamElbanna, that error disappeared, thanks, but got a warning now: `Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object' to 'T'. Reason: 'query.getResultList()' has raw type, so result of get is erased`: 
As a result, I get a compilationerror when I try this to get result from a column this way `resultList.getTestId();`

Comment: This is due to the casting, I have updated the answer to add `@SuppressWarnings`

Comment: Check the `getTestColmn()` in the question. `resultList` is not getting me the columns defined in the entity class after I applied your code. Please double-check. It should return columns from the entity class

Comment: Make sure you create the `DemoManager` with the `DemoEntity` type like `new DemoManager<DemoEntity>(...)`

Comment: @Testilla I have added another solution to have not add a generic to the class but turn the `executeQuery` into static

Comment: @IslamElbanna, thanks I am going with your first approach and it's looking good so far. I am getting a nullpointerException on this line:
 `session = Base.getSessionFactory(url, username, password, entity).openSession();`
Any ideas why?

Comment: @Testilla I guess it is not related to the main question, but I think could be some wrong parameters passed to `getSessionFactory` which make the function to return `null` that you try to open a connection

Comment: Also i think it is better to handle session closing in a try-resources instead to not have any leaks `try(session = Base.getSessionFactory(url, username, password, entity)){}` and the session count be local variable in this case